# Error starting UCMA TrustedApplication

Tags: c#, lync, ucma

When trying to run a TrustedApplication on a new machine, we get the following in our log.
The CsTrustedApplication and it's Pool have been defined, and the local management store is replicated.

The error:

```
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.ProvisioningFailureException:One or more values in the configured settings are invalid or unusable. Check inner exception and logs for more details. ---> Microsoft.Rtc.Internal.ServerConfiguration.SettingsInitializationException: The settings wrapper failed to initialize.
Unable to find  the Sqld database: Cannot open database "xds" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\user'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when the account you are running your app under doesn't have permissions to the replicated CMS database.

You will need to add the account you're running under to the 'RTC Component Local Group' security group on the application server, if you haven't already.

Comment: On the Lync server, or the server running the TrustedApplicationEndpoint?

Comment: On the application server - the one running the TrustedApplicationEndpoint

Comment: That changed something. Now we get a TLS certificate error instead. If we then set the application to run as "Administrator" it works. This is "funny" as the user were in the local Administrators group before setting him to 'RTC Component Local Group'.

Comment: Ah, OK - the account will also need access to read the local machine certificate from the cert store. The steps are slightly convoluted - search for "FindPrivateKey" in this article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh347354.aspx. Alternatively, leave the account in the local 'Administrators' group, as well as the 'RTC Component Local Group'

Comment: I won't get around to this before the Easter holidays, but from the looks of it, it is what we needed.

Comment: I meant to say **Thanks** after that last line. It posted the comment instead when I pressed enter to get a new line :P

Comment: Paul, if you don't mind me asking, what would I have to do differently if I want to move a functioning UCMA 3.0 trusted application outside the domain, in the form of a remotely hosted solution, or is that even possible? I will create another question on this for a proper recording of the reputation points if there is you like :)

Comment: I'm fairly sure this isn't supported for trusted applications, as the application server needs to be domain joined

Comment: It seems the URL Paul mentioned has moved, I think this one discusses the use of  FindPrivateKey.exe: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh347354(v=office.14).aspx